# Avoid recomputation of same values in double for loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop

Ok here is my simple code,

```
for ii = 1:3;
   for kk = 1:3;
      if ii~=kk
        z=ii+kk
       end
    end
end
```

I get the output,

1+2=3 AND 2+1=3

With the other combinations,

I only want either or of them, I don't want it to tell me the same answer.

Comment: This program does not run. At least 4 `end` statements are missing. Also please indent your code to make it easier to read.

Comment: Ok Nicky, thanks, yes I havent included the full program because it is long,

Comment: I am just trying to get an idea of how to sovle my problem

Comment: Where is`y=18X1+19X2` in your code? You don't have to include the full program if not all parts of the code are related to the question you asked, but you should at least [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: xinit=[data(:,ii),data(:,kk)];   
yinit=data(:,6);

Comment: Anthony that is how my regression is input

Comment: You need to rephrase your question with more information, it is very unclear what you are asking right now

Comment: @AnderBiguri I have tried to rephrase it

Comment: I edited the question for clarity, let me know if I removed relevant information.

Comment: perfect thanks good job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something in the lines of:

```
for ii = 1:3;
  for kk = (ii+1):3; % start from ii+1 as the others have already been calculated
    % if ii~=kk we dont need it anymore
       z=ii+kk
     %end
   end
end
```